# java switch case can not resolve to variable

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have a simple `switch case` case.

```
public static int setMapTile() {

    int a = getArmadaLength(); // 4 to 6 
    int b;
    switch (a) {

        case 4:
            System.out.println(" recommended MapSize : 10 x 10");
            b = setSize();// method for bigger map, return int

            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println(" recommended MapSize : 11 x 11");
            b = setSize();// method for bigger map, return int

            break;
        case 6:
            System.out.println(" recommended MapSize : 12 x 12");
            b = setSize();// method for bigger map, return int

            break;            
        default:
            System.out.println("wrong"); // even though it is impossible!
            break;
    }

    return b;
}
```

It says that `b` might not have been initialized. Do I have to use `setter` & `getter` to assign the chosen value to `b`?

Comment: Local variables should be initialized when it's declared. Please set b=0;

Comment: yes all local variables should be initialized for example int b =0, most commonly used, string answer = "", most commonly used etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JVM will look at all possible outcomes. 
One of them is:

```
default:
            System.out.println("wrong"); // even though it is impossible!
            break;
```

after which, you return b. 
But, since b is a local variable, it has no default value. You'll need to initialize it for all the possibilities, including the default one:

```
default:
            System.out.println("wrong"); // even though it is impossible!
            b = 0;
            break;
```

Or give b a value on declaration:

```
int b = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

No you do not need a setter. Simply initialize the variable: `int b = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you didn't initialized `b`. Set some default value as per your requirement, say, `int b=-1;`

Answer (score 0):

As the exception states, you never *initialize* b by assigning it a value if your switch should run its `default` case.

`int b;` merely *declares* it.

to fix your issue, you can simply change it to  `int b = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

At the point of `return b`, `b` should be initialised. It will be initialised in case `a` is `4`, `5` and `6`; but what if `a` is `28`? You're saying it shouldn't be able to happen, but things that shouldn't happen happen all the time, and the compiler likes to have all its bases covered.

Either initialise `b` at top to cover all cases, or make sure to assign it in each branch of the `switch` (including `default`).

Another possibility (which I actually like best) is to make sure your code can not reach `return` in the default case; you can throw an exception there (maybe `IllegalStateException`, "there is something wrong with the code!") and the compiler will then know it can't reach `return` through `default`, and not complain about `b` being unassigned. Your code should not happily proceed when your assumptions are violated, so this fits well.

```
public static int setMapTile() {
    int a = getArmadaLength(); // 4 to 6 
    int b;
    switch (a) {
        case 4:
            System.out.println(" recommended MapSize : 10 x 10");
            b = setSize();// method for bigger map, return int
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println(" recommended MapSize : 11 x 11");
            b = setSize();// method for bigger map, return int
            break;
        case 6:
            System.out.println(" recommended MapSize : 12 x 12");
            b = setSize();// method for bigger map, return int
            break;            
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("Armada length is " + a + "?!?");
            break;
    }
    return b;
}
```

In this specific case, actually, you can even factor out the `b` outside of the `switch` and completely avoid the problem. Also, that last `break` is redundant.

```
public static int setMapTile() {
    int a = getArmadaLength(); // 4 to 6 
    switch (a) {
        case 4:
            System.out.println(" recommended MapSize : 10 x 10");
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println(" recommended MapSize : 11 x 11");
            break;
        case 6:
            System.out.println(" recommended MapSize : 12 x 12");
            break;            
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("Armada length is " + a + "?!?");
    }
    return setSize();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a value to `b`, when you declare it or in the `default` block.

Instance fields have implicit default values when declared, but variables in methods do not.

```
public class Foo {
    private int age; // this defaults to 0

    public void bar() {
        int height; // this won't compile unless you follow it with an assignment
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Java compiler doesn't know that a can only be 4 to 6, so it considers the possibility of the default case. So if the default case of the switch is taken, then, b was never initialized when you do `return b`.

Answer (score 0):

There is chance that non of your cases in the `switch` gets executed and if that is the case, it ll come to the `default` block. In the `default` block, you are not setting the value of `b`. You never initialized `b` in the first place. That is why this is happening.

To avoid this situation, you can do one of the followings :

1. `int b = -1; // Initialize b`

2.

```
default: {
            System.out.println("wrong"); // even though it is impossible!
            b = -1;
            break;
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Either change this line: `int b;` to `int b = 0;`

Or change your code to this shorter variant:

```
public static int setMapTile() {

    int a = getArmadaLength(); // 4 to 6 
    switch (a) {

        case 4:
            System.out.println(" recommended MapSize : 10 x 10");
            return setSize();// method for bigger map, return int
        case 5:
            System.out.println(" recommended MapSize : 11 x 11");
            return setSize();// method for bigger map, return int
        case 6:
            System.out.println(" recommended MapSize : 12 x 12");
            return setSize();// method for bigger map, return int           
        default:
            System.out.println("wrong"); // even though it is impossible!
    }

    return 0;
}
```